# There is no row at position 0:c# code error

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

```
   DataRow dr = GetData("select * from Personal_det where Fid='" + va+"'").Rows[0];
    Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 88f, 88f, 10f, 10f);
    Font NormalFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 12, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK);
    using (System.IO.MemoryStream m = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
    {
        PdfWriter w = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, m);
        Phrase phrase = null;
        PdfPCell cell = null;
        PdfPTable table = null;
        BaseColor color = null;
        Paragraph para = null;
        Font times = null;
        BaseFont bfTimes = null;


        doc.Open();
        table = new PdfPTable(2);

        cell = PhraseCell(new Phrase("Faculty Profile", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 12, Font.UNDERLINE, BaseColor.BLACK)), PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER);
        //table.SpacingBefore = 20f;

        cell.Colspan = 2;
        table.AddCell(cell);
        cell = PhraseCell(new Phrase(), PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER);
        cell.Colspan = 2;
        cell.PaddingBottom = 30f;
```

[image: Error messsage]
This is my C# code.When i try to execute it gives the following error

I dont know from where i get the error,is it from code itself or the database.In some instance this code works,but for some instance it will give the following error..Can you clarify the error to me.?

If i use dr.rows.length..It doesnt shows the row keyword[image: No row keyword shown]

```
    private DataTable GetData(string query)
      {
    string conString =                              
     ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ProjectConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
    using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(conString))
    {
        using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter())
        {
            cmd.Connection = cn;
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
            {
                da.Fill(dt);
                return dt;
            }


        }
    }


}
```

This is the Getdata method..previously i had FID as string but now converted into varchar,I am struggling to get the right answer,please help to rebuild my code

Comment: that query doesn't return any data - works as expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hope this works....check dt for contents first then select its rows

```
 var dt = GetData("select * from Personal_det where Fid='" + Session["FID"] + "'");
        if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.Rows[0];// or do somthing

        }
          else
         {
           //No data

         }
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there was no row returned by your query... hence the exception.

try something like so...

```
var dt = GetData(".....your query");
if(dt != null && dt.Rows.Length > 0)
{
    var dr= dt.Rows[0]
    //do your stuff..
}
```

Comment: It shows system.datatable cannot be impicitly converted to system.datarow

Comment: remove `.Rows[0]` off the end of the `GetData` line.  You're trying to access `Rows` before anything is returned.  That's why you're getting the error.

Comment: I have tried with your code, But it is not giving any sort of output,i think not returning any data

Answer (score 1):

Do as below

```
DataTable dt = GetData("select * from Personal_det where Fid='" + va+"'");
```

put some validation as below

```
if(dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{

  DataRow dr = dt.Rows[0];
  // do something with dr.........

}
```

Comment: Its giving only RowError and RowState but not Rows

Comment: private DataTable GetData(string query)
    {
        string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ProjectConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(conString))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.Connection = cn;
                da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                {
                    da.Fill(dt);
                    return dt;
           }          }
 }

Comment: when you call `GetData` method don't put `.Rows[0]` at the end, do exactly as my answer

Comment: @Damith..Nothng is been displaying now after i changed it to your code

Comment: it is because GetData not returning data

Comment: @Damith..So what to do then next..?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37441/discussion-between-damith-and-shreyas-tg)

Comment: @Damith..I doesnt contains any data

Comment: Its a string,previously it was a number now converted to string

Comment: There is no row at position 0.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: There is no row at position 0.
  this is the error i am getting now

Answer (score 0):

The query returned no rows. You should check the length before attempting to access the data.

```
var dataTable = GetData(....);
if(dataTable.Rows.Length > 0) 
{
  // you can read row 0
}
else 
{ 
  // no rows
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this occurs occasionally(sometimes there are rows and sometimes there isnt) then its a data issue.
you should validate before accessing the row in order to handle zero records returned from this query

```
         DataRow dr = GetData("select * from Personal_det where Fid='" + va+"'");

         if (dr.Rows.Length> 0 )
          {
          //post your logic
          }
```

Comment: @Bsayej..For your more convenience you can look through the above image that i have attached the image.